# Do I understand the ArmorSeal 8100 instructions correctly?

Tags: epoxy

I'm going to use ArmorSeal 8100 on my garage floor. The instructions say:

> Concrete Floors, unpainted:
> 1 ct. ArmorSeal 8100 2.0-4.0 (50-100)
> (reduced with one pint of water per gallon)
> 2 cts. ArmorSeal 8100 2.0-4.0 (50-100)

This tells me that I should do -

1 coat of the ArmorSeal 8100 reduced with 1 pint of water per gallon

2 coats of ArmourSeal 8100 with 4:1 mix ratio with the hardener

Since I'm going glossy, I also wanted to do a topcoat of clear glossy ArmourSeal 8100 with anti skid mixed.

Does this sound right or are there any recommendations to do it a different way?

Comment: Nothing in the snippet you're provided is obviously a hardener ratio. If 4:1 is based on the numbers here, it's actually a range from 2:1 though 4:1 (suggesting 3:1 would be the happy place you're really aiming for) and your proposed methodology doesn't mention putting hardener in the first coat at all, which is likely an error. In any case, for paint-type products following the manufacturer's instructions **is** generally the best way to use them.

Comment: ArmorSeal 8100 is supposed to be mixed with hardener on a 4:1 on the first coat. My question is precisely about the confusing instructions -
1. Is my first coat supposed to be reduced with water or the one with hardener?
2. Am I supposed to coat that first water reduced coat with a hardener coat?
The manufacturer's instructions aren't clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Armorseal 8100 comes in both satin and gloss finish, so it doesn't make sense to me why you would choose to apply a gloss topcoat... just buy the gloss paint.

The published technical testing data is based on 2-coat application; 2 coats would be needed for the material to perform as advertised.

- it is always mixed at 4 parts (A) to one part (B)

> 1. Is my first coat supposed to be reduced with water or the one with hardener?

YES, for bare concrete the first coat is mixed with hardener at the normal ratio, then reduced (thinned) with 1 pint of water per gallon. This is considered the primer coat.

The second coat should be applied without reducer.

The full technical application sheet can be found here: [Armorseal 8100 Product Information](https://www.paintdocs.com/docs/webPDF.jsp?SITEID=SWPCGPROT&doctype=PDS&prodno=035777183953&lang=2)

Comment: You're just assuming that I'm NOT buying the gloss paint. So the primer coat is basically - 
4 part of A to 1 Part of B and that is reduced with 1 pint of water per gallon? Also, in the instructions it says - 
1 ct reduced
2 ct armorseal 8100. Doesn't that mean 3 coats?

Comment: No, it means 1st coat; 2nd coat. The tech sheet says 2 coats for unpainted concrete. Nothing I could find in the technical materials says anything about a clear (deep tint base, reduced) top coat over the gloss paint; I don't advise doing it.

Comment: Thank you for your help and clarification!